How does an atom change in the presence of a large gravitational force?
Question / light thought experiment on atomic structure in the presence of a large gravitation force.
Background:
This is a general, conceptual question, not looking to solve any particular problem, but still one that should have an answer, albeit a general one. I will use the phrase "distance from the nucleus" when describing electrons in an atom in this question. Please understand that I realize that electrons exist in a field of probability and when I say "distance from the nucleus" I am referring to the distance from the nucleus that describes a field in which there is a 90% chance of finding an electron of given energy level within it. I understand that electrons do not orbit the atom at a fixed distance.
This question is about how matter is compressed under gravity. Initially, I was thinking about the inside of black holes. I know matter is likely completely destroyed and turned into energy inside a black hole, however, so let's say at some level of gravity less than that of the inside of a black hole, but still very strong. Maybe a level experienced on approaching a black hole at some distance. The fundamental question is in what way is the matter compressed? Is it simply atoms are squeezed closer to each other until some point where they can no longer take it and eventually collapse (the scenario in the linked question below) or are the atoms themselves fundamentally, internally changed more gradually as they approach?
I did find a similar question here but my question is a more general, less extreme case and I want to know what understanding we currently have.
Setup
To illustrate in more detail, here's the setup I imagine (with lots of simplifications to try to get to the fundamental point):
Let's say I have a "magical" device that can somehow create a very strong, localized, gravitational field without a source of mass. Further I can use the device to restrict that gravitation field such that it only affects the things I want it to (i.e. it does not have an infinite range, I can restrict its range to a specific area regardless of how strong the field is). Again, this is a "magical" device as I have to violate some rules of physics to simplify the problem statement.
Let's say I also have "magical" instruments which can measure things inside and outside of this gravitational field from the same frame of reference (i.e. the instruments themselves are not affected by the gravitational field machine even if measuring things inside of it).
Let's say I have two atoms of Xenon. I place one of these atoms of Xenon inside of my magical gravity device and turn the gravity up very high. It is extremely strong gravity, but not strong enough gravity to destroy the atom. Let's also assume it's otherwise a vacuum inside of this device and the Xenon atom centers itself inside of this gravitational field - so, if there's any "spaghettification" effect, it would be the same at a given distance from the nucleus.
EDIT: Please assume that this gravitational field is the equivalent of a very large point mass centered in the center of the atom, though "magically" without that mass existing. So, it would be strongest at that point and weakening as it goes out. Assume the weakening is uniform in all directions.
Question
If I were to compare measurements of electron "orbitals" between these two Xenon atoms, what would I see? Would the orbitals look the same, or would they be "squeezed" in the atom that is inside the gravitational field?
For example, if I took measurements of shell K (1), would I find the typical 140 pm distance from the nucleus, or would that value now be decreased?
Big picture question: Assuming the field is not strong enough to tear the atom apart, do the effects of a strong gravitational field affect basic atomic structure the way we know it?

Just a note, what happens to matter at the singularity is unknown since the gravitational force is so strong that we really need a theory of quantum gravity to try and model it, stating that it becomes every is just pure speculation.

https://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1571 may be of interest.

"Squeezed" is kind of the wrong picture for what happens when an object is placed in an external gravitational field (it's a better word for an object that collapses under its own gravity). Instead, the object will be stretched by tidal forces. How much stretching will depend on the strength of the gravitational field relative to the electromagnetic forces responsible for the atomic orbitals. "Small" gravitational field --> can be treated rigorously by perturbation theory. "Large" gravitational field --> hard to say quantitatively but should lead to spaghettification eventually.

My intuitive guess would be that your atom will be long ionized and gone (and so will the nucleus) due to the firewall radiation inside a black hole before it ever reaches a region of high enough curvature to be seriously affected itself.

Is the strong gravitational field uniform or non uniform?

@Jagerber48 for simplification I was intending a uniform gravitational field.

Please note, even though I stated "Initially, I was thinking about black holes" my question is actually about "at some level of gravity less than that of the inside of a black hole, but still very strong" in other words, not at or in the singularity and at a level not strong enough to ionize it.

@Andrew you make a good point... with my simplifications it would act like an object under its own gravity. However, to the concept, I get that matter on approach to the strong gravity source will be stretched and "spaghettified" but isn't part of that spaghettification also an orthogonal "squeeze" at the same time? All that being said,  the root of my question is, are these effects of gravity, whether stretched or squeezed, happening at a relatively "macro" or subatomic level? Are the atoms themselves being stretched and squeezed or just the space between the atoms?

@Jagerber48 after reading JEB's answer below, I realize a uniform gravitational field is actually NOT what I intended, as that would cancel out the forces in all direction. I intended "uniform at a given distance" Think of it as being a large point mass in the center of the atom and the gravitational field that would result. I will edit my question to clarify this.

I think the answer is "nothing". An atom in a strong gravitational field is going to do one thing: fall. As in free-fall, aka "zero gee". Hence: nothing.
Spaghettification occurs in a strong field with a strong gradient (aka, tidal forces). The field can be Taylor expanded:
$$ \vec g(z') = -(g_0 - \frac 1 2 g' z')\hat z $$
where $g' > 0$ is the rate of increase of the field in the direction of the field. Now we're in free fall, so we subtract $-g_0\hat z$ and work un primed coordinates:
$$ \vec g(z) = \vec g(z') + g_0\hat z = \frac 1 2 g' z $$
which can be integrated to get a perturbing potential:
$$ \Phi_g(z) = g'z^2 $$
for a perturbation:
$$ H_g(z) = \mu g'z^2 $$
where $\mu$ is the reduced mass. Ofc, I am going to use a hydrogen atom because the is zero reason use xenon with 54 separate coordinates.
The Hamiltonian is:
$$ H(\vec r) = H_{\rm Coulomb}(r) + H_g(z) $$
$$ H(\vec r) = \frac{\hat p^2}{2\mu} - \frac{e^2} r + \mu g'z^2 $$
Note that:
$$ \frac{z^2}{r^2} = \sqrt{\frac 2 3} Y_2^0(\theta, \phi) + \sqrt{\frac 1 3} Y_0^0(\theta, \phi) $$
so the perturbation is a constant plus a quadrapole operator, so you can use standard perturbation theory to calculate the energy shifts or the 1st order wave functions. If the energy shift gets close to 13.8 eV, then you need to worry about ripping the atom apart.

I disagree.The energy states of a atom can be found by the time-independent Schrodinger equation.But it assumes that coordinate and proper length is the same which is not any longer the case under a strong gravitational field.You need to include corrections from the metric and since now the new version has a  non-linear differential equations ,it can deviate a lot by just adding a gravitational potential.

Thank you for the insight. I may have made a mistake in my simplification. A uniform gravitational field like I implied, would be pulling the same in all directions and cancel out the forces. I appreciate that you spelled out all the equations rather than dismissing the question altogether though, it helps me understand. I also think @RootGroves has a point and would love to see the modifications that incorporate his comments or subsequent discussion.

So that is electrodynamics in curved spacetime (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations_in_curved_spacetime). If you're not familiar with 4-vector special relativity or differential geometry in GR, it won't make much sense. Very few GR problems are analytically solvable.

The time-independent Schrodinger equation which describes the energy levels of a atom is solved by asuming that coordinate and proper length are the same.But under strong gravitational effects that is not the case so you can correlate the coordinate length to the proper length according to the metric and solve that equation from there.This may not be entirely correct but it is a useful approximation.

Thank you for the answer / comment. Part of my question stems from my ignorance of general relativity, but also my curiosity of cases where quantum theory and relativity meet (by that I mean where you have to take their effects into account). I am familiar with proper length as it is used in special relativity and different inertial FORs. I had assumed that the effects of gravity on length would be observed the same even from different inertial or even non-inertial FORs. Your response suggests that's not the case and I need to dig into that more.

The reason it change is that the under the new version the time-independent Schrodinger equation which describes a atom becomes non-linear so its results can deviate a lot from the case where the gravitational potential was negligible.
